# How is it possible to apply electrical engineering knowledge adequately in such different, variating devices?

Tags: integrated-circuit, design

I realize people do learn it somewhat linearly and progressively, but like the power of a human body in exercising, intelligence or knowledge is not 100% linear. To avoid making this a further off-topic and philosophical/mathematical question, I would like to ask those here who have a much better knowledge all around than a noobster like me:

How is it possible to transfer the working knowledge from two completely different electrical devices (computer monitor to hard drive firmware) and not get "lost" between the variations of implementation and structure? I mean I realize a lot of the stuff electronic devices work with is transferrable and overlapping, but I mean more specifically in the approach to starting up, i.e. "We begin design plan of monitor now with....". How do you people know how to start everything off so well, despite variations in devices that differ in implementation, difficulty, mechanical/electrical configurations, like ICs in a CRT TV to a graphics processing unit. How do you follow through with the approach and not get lost in the burden of implementation confusion?

Sorry for the long winded questioning, but I just generally want to know how you gain the fundamental knowledge to manage this in full without endless references, "learn on the spots", especially with endless advancing devices, newer components, etc.

I am a beginner wondering this, because the idea of understanding the workings of a CRT TV all the way to a GPU seems like a nightmare.

Comment: It's a bit like cooking - you get the hang of a few recipes then try some more then start to mix a few things up etc.. How do musicians write music let alone play it.

Comment: Aw, great example! That clears it up a bit more. I guess it's not just the know how, but the done how!

Comment: Don't forget the factor of specialization. In applications of some complexity you don't have one genius mastermind developing every detail on his own. There are teams involved with persons or groups responsible for the details of a certain sub-components. People developing RAM chips need not know about how CPUs are designed or what's good practice for power supplies, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of experience actually. With the time (theory and practice) you will learn to divide the very complex task to subtasks and then to sub-sub-tasks and so on, until you reach very simple subtask that to be easy to understand and design.

Always try to thing structurally. Every system has some hierarchical structure and this structure is the first you need to analyze and understand, before trying to analyze the parts of the structure.

Comment: I figured that, but how does one tackle completely different, multi-purpose workings or "innards" of devices that may be outside the simple scope of electrical engineering, i.e. mechanical functions, or more "physics-related" kind of design? What about electromechanics?

Comment: Well, nothing is fully "outside the scope" of electronics. :) If you are working on bigger and bigger projects, early or later you will learn a lot of side knowledge about mechanics, pneumatics and many areas where electronics may take place. It all is matter of time, work and patience.

Comment: @USER: it's actually the same in every kind of engineering: there are basic physics laws, you learn them, you investigate lots of examples about how those laws are normally used in real life, how components work, then you investigate lots of examples about how components are normally put together, and then you'll start to have a broader and broader knowledge of how things are to be constructed. You _have to_ know the principles behind, how the components work, and you _have to_ look at the whole picture as well.

Answer (score 1):

Standardization.  Ever hear of IEEE 802.3?  IEEE 802.11?  PCI?  PCI Express? IEEE 1394?  USB?  DDR?  DDR2?  DDR3?  HDMI?  There are standards organizations that figure out how to implement these interfaces and write pages and pages of specifications that define the voltages, frequencies, formats, connectors, etc. and then everyone who wants to implement these interfaces has to follow the specification to a T otherwise their hardware won't work with anyone else's.

Want to build a monitor?  License the HDMI spec and then build your monitor to receive it and decode it correctly.  Want to build a new memory module?  License the DDR3 spec and build your memory to the electrical and timing characteristics specified.  Want your device to support wifi?  License IEEE 802.11 and build your radios to support that standard.

Comment: Sure, that's obvious, but that's not what I meant. I meant how do you go from x chipset to y sound chip without knowing more detail-specific orientations of those designs and purposes themself? Do all electrical/computer engineers know how sound chips work, and how chipsets do?

Comment: Well, if you're going to interface with a chip, you definitely need to know enough about what you're interfacing with to support it.  Now, as far as a chipset and a sound card are concered, the people designing the chipset and sound card just design to PCI or PCI express and then let the software people get the details figured out in the driver.  Things like chipsets, when designed correctly, are more or less transparent.  So long as everything implements all the right busses correctly, it's not too hard to write a driver for the sound card that doesn't depend on a specific chipset.

Comment: Incorrect. Although the software developers will be interfacing the hardware, the hardware engineers (electrical engineers) must develop the entire scope of the hardware's functioning, covering every entire aspect of the circuit. The software developers can't interface what isn't developed accordingly.

Comment: How is that incorrect?  If the chipset is designed correctly, a memory read or write transaction in PCI memory mapped space is converted to a PCI transaction and sent over the PCI bus.  Who cares where it is going.  Some device on the bus then responds (or not) and the response is sent back up to the driver.  The only specification that the chipset and sound card need to support is PCI.  Period.  The specifics of controlling the sound card are managed by the device driver, and no hardware needs to be privy to the details besides the sound card.